# Why the radial topology on $ \mathbb R^2 $ is not second countable?

Tags: general-topology

> A subset $ U\subset\mathbb R^2 $ is *radially open* if for every $ x\in U $ and every $ v\in\mathbb R^2 $, there exists $ \epsilon>0 $ such that $ x+sv\in U $ for every $ s\in (-\epsilon, \epsilon) $. Then the collection of radially open sets defines a topology on $ \mathbb R^2 $. Let $ X $ be $ \mathbb R^2 $ equipped with the radially open topology.

Prove that $ X $ is not second countable.

The question is extracted from: (16) of https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/files/week2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not even first-countable. Let $\{U_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable family of neighbourhoods of $(0,0)$, say.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $v_n$ be the unit vector that makes an angle of $2^{-n}$ with the positive $x$-axis and let $\varepsilon_n$ be such that $\lambda v_n\in U_n$ whenever $|\lambda|<\varepsilon_n$.
Define $U$ to be the set that contains for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ only the points $\lambda v_n$ with $|\lambda|<\varepsilon_n/2$ and for all other unitvectors, $v$, all points of the form $\lambda v$ with $\lambda>0$.

Show that $U$ is open in $X$ but that it contains none of the $U_n$.

Comment: I don't see why $U$ is a neighbourhood of all points in the x-axis. I would say through some of them there may be lines(the vertical ones, for example) such that  its intersections with $U$ would not contain an interval  centered at the point

Comment: @Seven: You appear to be correct. If, for instance, $U_n$ is the Euclidean open ball of radius $2^{-n}$ centred at the origin, points on the positive $x$-axis will be limits (along vertical lines) of points of $\Bbb R^2\setminus U$.

Comment: so this method doesn't work, How can we fix it?

Comment: Hmm maybe when you say " contains for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ only the points $\lambda v_n$ with $|\lambda| < \epsilon_n/2$" it should also say  "and with  $|\lambda| > \epsilon_n/2$. That is, we only eliminate a point in each line. Would it work like this?

Comment: I'm seeing that the problem is choosing the epsilons in a way no subsequence is alligned

Answer (score 3):

Make the observation that the circle is discrete. Justify that if $C$ is a circle, then for every $x\in C$, $(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus C)\cup\{x\}$ is open. Since this topology is clearly finer than the metric topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the circle is also closed. Since the circle is an uncountable closed discrete set, this topology is not Lindel$\ddot{\text{o}}$f and therefore not second countable either.